# Merging list of dictionaries with a single dictionary based on same value

Tags: python-3.x, list, dictionary, merge

I have the following dict & list of dicts:

```
dict1 = {21409: 'docx', 44334: 'xlsx', 33635: 'jpg'}
list_of_dicts= [{"Customer":"test1","Field1":"yy","Field2":"bb","FileExtension":"jpg"},{"Customer":"test2","Field1":"aa","Field2":"bb","FileExtension":"docx"},{"Customer":"test3","Field1":"cc","Field2":"yy","FileExtension":"xlsx"}]
```

Having pairs of *key* and *value* from **dict1**, I want to add that *key* to dictionary from **list_of_dict** which has same value for *FileExtension*.

In other words, I want to update each dictionary from **list_of_dict** based on its *FileExtension* value, adding new key: *Count*, while values to be updated for each *FileExtension* are in **dict1**.

Desired output:

```
[{"Customer":"test1","Field1":"yy","Field2":"bb","FileExtension":"jpg","Count":33635},{"Customer":"test2","Field1":"aa","Field2":"bb","FileExtension":"docx","Count":21409},{"Customer":"test3","Field1":"cc","Field2":"yy","FileExtension":"xlsx","Count":44334}]
```

I have tried a few methods but it did not go so well.
It seems a bit tricky.
Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can reverse your *dict1* for easier manipulation and then update your *list_of_dicts* as follow:

```
d = {value: key for key, value in dict1.items()}
for x in list_of_dicts:
  x["Count"] = d[x["FileExtension"]]
```

Then output for *list_of_dicts*

```
[{'Customer': 'test1',
  'Field1': 'yy',
  'Field2': 'bb',
  'FileExtension': 'jpg',
  'Count': 33635},
 {'Customer': 'test2',
  'Field1': 'aa',
  'Field2': 'bb',
  'FileExtension': 'docx',
  'Count': 21409},
 {'Customer': 'test3',
  'Field1': 'cc',
  'Field2': 'yy',
  'FileExtension': 'xlsx',
  'Count': 44334}]
```